# Moving system files or Windows Folder

Tags: windows

1. Is it possible to move anything inside the Windows folder (like system 32) or any other folder into the desktop, or would the Trustedinstaller.exe not allow it?

2.Will the same thing apply if I were to move the Windows folder itself into the desktop?

Of course I wouldn’t do it to my own computer, I’m curious to know. Your help is greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: You can try to move those files but you won’t be able to.  Those files that do move, I guarantee you, will result in a system that will not boot into Windows.  Since your not actually interested in doing this, I will point out that curiosity killed the cat, and vote to close this question since what you want isn’t practical nor should you attempt it

Comment: Windows makes no provision for moving the Windows folder or any of it's subfolders. This cannot be done from within Windows. If done outside of Windows, expect an unbootable system.

Comment: There are some folders which are trivial and can be moved. The important folders cannot be moved, true. Verified this by experiment on my desktop. See below. It still boots, BTW.

Comment: Why would you want to move system files/folders to the desktop?  If you want quick access to them, just create shortcuts to those items on your desktop.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, some unimportant items can be moved without consequence, such as the `Best Practices` folder, which I just verified. Others cannot, e.g., the Windows folder, and trying is counterproductive.